# Car simulator - Infinite loop

Tags: c++, class, infinite-loop

I am creating a car simulator program and I am getting an infinite loop when I run it. I added a break; at the end of the while loop, but then it just displays mileage: 1 -- Fuel Level: 15. I also noticed that in the infinite loop, the fuel level is not changing it just stays at 15. I have looked over my code and have tried to debug it but I cant seem to find it. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you

UPDATE: It now runs good. The fuel level is decreasing from 15 but the mileage is starting at 1 and increasing to 15 which is incorrect, any ideas why?
**The maximum mileage the odometer can store is 999,999 miles. When this amount is exceeded, the odometer resets the current mileage to 0.

It should decrease the FuelGauge object’s current amount of fuel by 1 gallon for every **24 miles traveled**. (The car’s fuel economy is 24 miles per gallon.)
Simulate filling the car up with fuel, and then run a loop that increments the odometer until the car runs out of fuel. During each loop iteration, print the car’s current mileage and amount of fuel.

```
        //While loop and display 
        while (fuelG.getCurrentAmtFuel() > 0)
        {
            odm.incrementCurrentMileage();
            cout << "Mileage: " << odm.getCurrentAmtMiles() << endl;
            cout << "Fuel Level: " << fuelG.getCurrentAmtFuel() << " gallons" << endl;
            break;
        }
```

While loop is now :

```
while (fuelG.getCurrentAmtFuel() > 0)
    {
        odm.incrementCurrentMileage();
        cout << "Mileage: " << odm.getCurrentAmtMiles() << endl;
        cout << "Fuel Level: " << fuelG.getCurrentAmtFuel() << " gallons" << endl;
        fuelG.decrementFuelTank();
    }
```

---

```
    //FuelGauge.h
    #ifndef FUELGAUGE_H
    #define FUELGAUGE_H
    using namespace std;
    class FuelGauge
    {
        private:
            int currentAmtFuel; //Holds current amount of fuel 

        public:
            FuelGauge (int gallons) // Current amount of fuel in gallons 
            {
                currentAmtFuel = gallons;
            }

            FuelGauge(); //Constructor 

            int getCurrentAmtFuel () //Gets the current amount of fuel and returns it 
            {
                return currentAmtFuel;
            }

            void incrementFuelTank() //Increments the fuel tank 
            {
                if (currentAmtFuel < 15)
                {
                    currentAmtFuel++;
                }
            }

            void decrementFuelTank() //Decrements the fuel tank 
            {
                if (currentAmtFuel > 0)
                {
                    currentAmtFuel--;
                }
            }
    };

    #endif
```

---

```
//Odometer.h
#include "FuelGauge.h"


#ifndef ODOMETER_H
#define ODOMETER_H
class Odometer
{
    private:
        int currentAmtMiles; //Holds current amount of miles 
        FuelGauge *fuelG; //Creates fuelG under FuelGauge
        //FuelGauge *f;

    public:
        Odometer(int miles, FuelGauge *f) //odometer function 
        {
            currentAmtMiles = miles;
            fuelG = f;
        }

        int getCurrentAmtMiles () //Function to get the amount of miles 
        {
            return currentAmtMiles;
        }

        void incrementCurrentMileage() //Increment mileage function 
        {
            if(currentAmtMiles < 999999)
            {
                currentAmtMiles++;
            }
            else 
                currentAmtMiles = 0;
        }


};

#endif
```

Comment: You could step through with a debugger to see where it gets stuck. Also, please try and post a *minimal* example.

Comment: Is there, anything that decrements `FuelGauge::currentAmtFuel` that is used in your workflow? I can't see any code that does it. So, the `currentAmtFuel` never reaches 0, and results in an infinite loop.

Comment: You're never calling `decrementFuelTank()` so it never gets to 0.

Answer (score 3):

The function `Odometer::incrementCurrentMileage()` does nothing to decrement the fuel in `FuelGuage`. I assume you want it to call `fuelG->decrementFuelTank)`.

Answer (score 0):

This loop:

```
while (fuelG.getCurrentAmtFuel() > 0) {
    odm.incrementCurrentMileage(); cout << "Mileage: " << odm.getCurrentAmtMiles() << endl;
    cout << "Fuel Level: " << fuelG.getCurrentAmtFuel() << " gallons" << endl; 
    break;
}
```

Should be either:

```
while (fuelG.getCurrentAmtFuel() > 0) {
    odm.incrementCurrentMileage(); cout << "Mileage: " << odm.getCurrentAmtMiles() << endl;
    cout << "Fuel Level: " << fuelG.getCurrentAmtFuel() << " gallons" << endl; 
    fuelG.decrementFuelTank();
}
```

If it makes sense to decrease the fuel tank. Otherwise use simply an `if` statement:

```
if (fuelG.getCurrentAmtFuel() > 0) {
    odm.incrementCurrentMileage(); cout << "Mileage: " << odm.getCurrentAmtMiles() << endl;
    cout << "Fuel Level: " << fuelG.getCurrentAmtFuel() << " gallons" << endl; 
}
```

Otherwise it is never allowed to exit the loop itself, for `fuelG.getCurrentAmtFuel()` will continue to be greater than `0`.

Comment: Okay it now displays the fuel level decreasing, but the mileage is starting at 1 and going to 15. That part is not correct any ideas why?

Comment: @s.marie, what do you expect it to be?

Comment: The maximum mileage the odometer can store is 999,999 miles. When this amount is exceeded, the odometer resets the current mileage to 0.  
It should decrease the FuelGauge object’s current amount of fuel by 1 gallon for every 24 miles traveled. (The car’s fuel economy is 24 miles per gallon.)  
Simulate filling the car up with fuel, and then run a loop that increments the odometer until the car runs out of fuel. During each loop iteration, print the car’s current mileage and amount of fuel.

Comment: It was so obvious that I missed it. You did right not to put those details in the question.